# MySQL operator like do not find records. Equal operator do

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I have a MySQL query with a weird behavior.

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email like 'john@doe.com'
```

Do not return any line

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = 'john@doe.com'
```

Returns one line

I have solved my problem replacing the LIKE to the = (equal) operator, since in MySQL it's case insensitive... But I really what to know why the MySQL have this unusual behavior just in this specific case (most cases it works like expected).

Comment: Both return one line for me.

Comment: @DanielRibeiro I can't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. As per my SQL Fiddle here (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25fb7/6) both like and = returns the same result.

Comment: Like I said, it just happens few times.
I have more than 50k registers in my table. Before insert in this table, I check to assure the email isn't already used... The SELECT returns no rows, so I insert and then I get an error from my unique index in this table...